# DOM - select a specific property of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, dom, events, jquery-selectors

I am playing with DOM **events delegations** and trying to figure out why I can't select a specific HTML element besides the **ID** property.

```
var html = ' <div class="item__clearfix" id="770" prop2="100"><div 
            class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div 
            class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete-- 
            btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'

document.querySelector('.item__clearfix').addEventListener('click', function(event){
      console.log(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
});
```

The parentNode I should get is: *div class="item__clearfix" id="770"*

When I select it's ID property, I can get the "770", but if I try to select a different property, I will get unidentified. Why is that?

```
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id >> 770
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.prop2 >> unidentified
```

Sorry if I didn't explain it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAttribute('property_name')` to get other attributes because id is accessible publicly.

Comment: so for EVERY other property, the getAttribute will do?

Comment: Yes, getAttribute will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `element.id` gets the calculated **id** of element when you use it as a DOM object. For other attributes which are not properties of an object, you need to use `.getAttribute()` becuase there is no caluclated property of DOM object with the **prop2** name.

```
event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("prop2")
```